# exec for libreoffice always returns success

Tags: php, exec, libreoffice, shell-exec

I have the following code in PHP to convert a .doc to pdf using libreoffice:

```
exec('libreoffice --headless --convert-to pdf sample.doc',$output,$return);

print_r($return);
```

This prints: `0` meaning success and converted file is also available

However, when I run:

```
exec('libreoffice --headless --convert-to pdf sample_not_there.doc',$output,$return);

print_r($return);
```

where sample_not_there.doc does not exist, it still prints `0` and the converted file obviously is not available too.

I want to know if the command was successfully executed or not everytime I run it. Is there a defined way to do it?

Comment: why don't you check file exist before running this command?

Comment: I would still need an error notification for exec if something else goes wrong with the command.

Comment: yes you will notify error if file not exist! or just don't run this command exec if file not exist!!

Comment: to get more result specific errors use $output also.. and research libreoffice in more details.